# Ordering of multiple align bottom components in C++Builder / VCL

Tags: c++builder, vcl

In our main form, we have a TStatusBar whose Align property is alBottom, and is set at design time.  When the program is started, if a particular flag is set, we create another form dynamically, set its parent to the main form, and set it's Align to alBottom as well (and deal with borders and other things).  Sometimes the dynamically-created form sits above the status bar, and sometimes below it.  We want it to always be above the status bar.  Is there a way to guarantee the ordering?  This is C++Builder 10.1

Comment: Make sure the `TStatusBar` is created and aligned before the 2nd Form is created, and make sure the 2nd Form is put inside the main Form's client area before being aligned.  Maybe also manually set the 2nd Form's coordinates above the `TStatusBar` before settings its alignment.

Comment: Should also have mentioned that the dynamic form can change size, and when aligned bottom and the size changes, the status bar and form may switch places.

Answer (score 0):

I would try a panel which can be hidden at first. That being said a form added at design time could be hidden as well.